# No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

I am receiving the following exception when I call redisDb.GetSetringAsync() from Redis Cache Client C# .Net core 2.1. In server, the same client application is working fine.

I tried:

- restarting azure redis cache server
- with both primary and secondary connection strings
- with synctimeout in connection string as well

Nothing helps.

> No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host |    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1 source, Exception unthrownException) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2000  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisExtensions.HashMemberGetAsync(IDatabase cache, String key, String[] members)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.DistributedCacheExtensions.GetStringAsync(IDistributedCache cache, String key, CancellationToken token)

Comment: Can you show your code?